# Columns and Inline elements, vertical align wrong

Tags: html, css

I have a ul of inline elements (checkbox and span)

For some rows (li's) I need two columns
I tried with float but that brakes the vertical alignment between the two columns
, but(!) when I created a fiddle for this question it works with the above technique! :/

I even cut and pasted our sites complete style into fiddle but I cant reproduce the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9g2C/

As you can see **Bar1** and **Some info** are vertically aligned.

If I disable font-size: 0.85em; from the body it aligns also on my site, doesn't matter if I use em or px if I have a size defined in the CSS it will not align. Can you guys tell me whats wrong?

**edit:** My question is what could cause the span and the input to not align in my real world site (I was not able to reproduce the alignment problem in the fiddle above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must simply add [this is in the normalize.css file of fiddle]

```
input{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

The checkbox input must have some kind of offset that is showing on anything floated next to it.

Comment: You cant replace the labels with divs, the wont be clickable then. There most be a common problem why it renders correctly in fiddle on not on the real site, I tried using the same doc type as fiddle did nothing.

Comment: *You can add the labels inside the div if you want to make it clickable. Here, i changed it.

Comment: My solution works on fiddle so i want to know what could mess it up on the real site.

Comment: The preview in fiddle should have a disclaimer that it's embedded in an iframe, which is going to make a lot of things appear differently than in a full mode browser.  Iframes are known for causing lots of problems. They really should not be used anymore.

Comment: iframe or no iframe doesn't matter in this case, for some reason the input / label and the floating span is in alignment http://fiddle.jshell.net/Q9g2C/show/light/ but not on the actual site

Comment: Fiddle is using a "normalize.css" file that includes the:  input{margin:0; padding:0;} .  If you add that to your css it will work.  Otherwise it will offset a floated span for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Its your image tag which is aligned on the top of your H1 tag.
I just removed the  tag in "header" div
[Corrected JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9g2C/3/)

Comment: Thanks, thats the Company logo, but please change it to a comment on my question instead because it does not answer the question

Answer (score 2):

I made some edits to your jsfiddle page.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9g2C/4/

A trick I have learned is to put a simple colored border around everything in question so you can see what is going on.  I didn't complete everything, but it is all css related.  By adding some padding, it helps to knock things in the place they should go.  The borders help you to SEE what is being pushed out of alignment.

Continue to play around with the css.

Comment: Looking at HaroonAbbasi's answer though, that looks good.  My answer is good for many things going forward though.  Just a good tool to keep in mind.

Comment: Its built in firebug to get borders around all elements

Comment: The unfortunate thing is one site looks totally different across browsers...example Craptastic IE.  So, css borders help in those situations.